# Nested Subquery Limitations in Oracle

Tags: oracle

So, I have been doing a fair amount of reading on this in various forums and resource sites but have not yet found found a solution I believe applies to my case. Also, I can't believe how difficult this is proving to be; I would think this kind of query would be fairly common.

Essentially what I am doing here is querying two historical tables (tbl_b and tbl_c), via union, for a specific milestone date - for which there may be multiple results... I then wish to find the most recent of these results, using max. This date is then returned as a column in the main query.

My problem is that, in the 3rd tier subquery, I need to reference an identifier value from the table in the top query (tbl_a).

I know that correlated queries only are able to reference their parent query - so, I am stuck.

**Edit 1**
The target date I am searching for will most likely, but not necessarily, be unique within the result set. It is a timestamp of the data record. I am looking for the most recent entry in the history that correlates to each column in tbl_a. Creating an SQL Fiddle for this.

See sample below:

```
select  tbl_a.col_a,
        tbl_a.col_b,
     (
        select  max(target_date)
        from
        (
            select  tbl_b.target_date
            from    tbl_b
            where   tbl_b.tbl_a_id = tbl_a.id and
                    tbl_b.flag = 1 and
                    tbl_b.milestone_id = tbl_a.milestone_id

            union

            select  tbl_c.target_date
            from    tbl_c
            where   tbl_c.tbl_a_id = tbl_a.id and
                    tbl_c.flag = 1 and
                    tbl_c.milestone_id = tbl_a.milestone_id
        ) most_recent_target_date
    )
from tbl_a
```

Comment: 1) Could you provide a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data to illustrate your problem? 2) Are the .target_date values unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert this query to a join, in this way:

```
select  tbl_a.col_a,
        tbl_a.col_b,
        max(most_recent_target_date.target_date)
from tbl_a
join (
            select  tbl_b.target_date, tbl_b.date_id
            from    tbl_b
            where   tbl_b.flag = 1 

            union all

            select  tbl_c.target_date, tbl_c.date_id
            from    tbl_c
            where   tbl_c.flag = 1 
) most_recent_target_date
ON tbl_a.date_id = most_recent_target_date.date_id
GROUP BY tbl_a.col_a,
         tbl_a.col_b
```